# Firebase Push Notification not working with API 28

Tags: android, firebase, push-notification, firebase-cloud-messaging

I am setting up firebase push notification, and as per the documentation I did everything I guess

So what I did is from Tools > Firebase > Cloud Messaging added Dependencies see my gradle

```
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:11.8.0'
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:11.8.0'
implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads:11.8.0'
```

After this I created a Class MyyFirebaseMessagingService and extended FirebaseMessagingService see below

```
public class MyFirebaseMessagingService extends FirebaseMessagingService {
@Override
public void onMessageReceived(RemoteMessage remoteMessage) {
    super.onMessageReceived(remoteMessage);

    Log.d("RefreshedToken", "onMessageReceived: " + remoteMessage.getNotification().getBody());
    showNotification(remoteMessage.getNotification().getBody());
}

private void showNotification(String message) {
    PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, 0, new Intent(this, MainActivity.class), 0);
    Notification notification = new Notification.Builder(this)
            .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.logo)
            .setContentTitle("Quotes App")
            .setContentText(message)
            .setContentIntent(pendingIntent)
            .setAutoCancel(true)
            .build();

    NotificationManagerCompat notificationManager = NotificationManagerCompat.from(this);
    notificationManager.notify(0, notification);
}}
```

After this I addeed Service in the manifest

```
<service
        android:name=".MyFirebaseMessagingService"
        android:enabled="true"
        android:exported="true"
        >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="com.google.firebase.MESSAGING_EVENT"/>
        </intent-filter>
  </service>
```

And now when I try to send notification I dont receive it. What am I doing wrong

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> > Create a channel and set the importance
>
> Before you can deliver the notification on Android 8.0 and higher, you
>   must register your app's notification channel with the system by
>   passing an instance of NotificationChannel to
>   createNotificationChannel().

As the [documentation](https://developer.android.com/training/notify-user/build-notification#java) say, you need to add a notification channel in android 8 and higher so the system shows your notification.

```
private void createNotificationChannel() {
    // Create the NotificationChannel, but only on API 26+ because
    // the NotificationChannel class is new and not in the support library
    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.O) {
        CharSequence name = getString(R.string.channel_name);
        String description = getString(R.string.channel_description);
        int importance = NotificationManager.IMPORTANCE_DEFAULT;
        NotificationChannel channel = new NotificationChannel(CHANNEL_ID, name, importance);
        channel.setDescription(description);
        // Register the channel with the system; you can't change the importance
        // or other notification behaviors after this
        NotificationManager notificationManager = getSystemService(NotificationManager.class);
        notificationManager.createNotificationChannel(channel);
    }
}
```

Comment: After doing this, I can see in the dashboard that notification has been sent to n devices but not receiving the notification in either of them

Comment: do you get the "RefreshedToken" in the log?

Comment: After doing what you said I reinstalled the application and app is working fine now

Answer (score 1):

1. First of all, you need to create notification channel...and channel id should be between 1 to 10.
2. Secondly, upgrade to the latest version of libraries in app/gradle.build
3. If app is in the foreground (visible to user), `onMessageReceived()` is called.
4. If app is in the background (not visible to user), then, `onMessageReceived()` isn't called and notification is automatically shown to user, without you manually showing them...and data values are passed as intent extras to you launcher activity when clicked.